# Shortcode not parsing in page template - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I've created a 404 error page in Wordpress and am trying include a contact form in the 404.php template.  So, I've installed the "Fast secure contact form" plugin and have created a post that includes the shortcode for said plugin.  When I view the post for this plugin the contact form shows properly.  When I try to manually inject the post into the 404.php template using:
        $page_id = 4015;
    $page_object = get_post( $page_id );
    echo $page_object->post_content;

The shortcode just displays as text.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it like this, add the shortcode to your 404 page.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[si-contact-form form="1"]'); ?>
```

You need not have to create a new post for the contact form.